# How can I write specifications following the W3C specifications format in LaTeX?

Tags: html, javascript

W3C specifications follow a very nice template (example: [HTML-RDFa](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-rdfa/)). The specifications are HTML documents styled by a javascript library [ReSpec](http://www.w3.org/respec/guide.html). Is it possible to write specifications in LaTeX following the same guidelines, but by using native LaTeX commands?

I am currently writing specifications in LaTeX, which eventually will be published as HTML with the ReSpec js library. ALthough it would be extremely convenient, it is not necessary to be able to convert the latex file into HTML and JS code later. I only want to follow the same style as the W3C specs in my current LaTeX document, while they are being drafted in LaTeX.

I guess I have to write the style file myself, but I am hoping it has been done before so I don't have to start from scratch.

Comment: Could your give a bit more detail here: I'm not sure quite what is needed. For example, are you expecting to read HTML or XML and typeset it, have a LaTeX input format, ...?

Comment: @JosephWright I added some detail, hoping that that clarifies it a bit.

Comment: The [W3C MathML recommendation pdf version](http://www.w3.org/Math/draft-spec/mathml.pdf) is typeset by LaTeX but I don't really keep to the same style. For MathML2 also has a [screen formatted pdf](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-MathML2-20010221/PDF-s-MathML-20010221.pdf) which was closer to the HTML style, and again set with LaTeX but we dropped that at MathML3.

Comment: If you are not authoring in HTML why use respec? why not just generate the final html directly from your latex sources?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't understand the question.

Comment: @Johannes_B don't answer it then:-)